# packages cannot be nested

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

its giving error on importing mx.resource.resourcebundle that packages cannot be nested

```
package common
{
    import common.clsGlobals;

    import flash.desktop.NativeProcess;
    import flash.desktop.NativeProcessStartupInfo;
    import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
    import flash.events.NativeProcessExitEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.filesystem.File;
    import flash.filesystem.FileMode;
    import flash.filesystem.FileStream;

    import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
    import mx.controls.Alert;
    //import mx.events.FileEvent;
    import mx.resources.*;
```

Comment: Hi, I usually get this when one of my defined packages does not reflect the folder path he is positioned into. Check that first ;)

Comment: is this inside a .as file or a .mxml file?

Comment: let us know the full listing of code

Answer (score 0):

That's some stupid Flex Builder error that usually says that you have some other error in your application and sometimes - that you have no errors at all. Clean you project (Project menu -> Clean) and it should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get this error if the given code is part of an `<mx:Script></mx:Script>` tag in an mxml file. That can happen when you use the `<mx:Script source="filename.as"/>` method to include ActionScript to your mxml components. If that is the case here, you can fix it by deleting the `package` block.

<sub>I'd rather copy the code into the CDATA block inside the `<mx:Script>` tag than keeping it in a separate file, but that's your choice.</sub>